# Joomla 3.3: Smart Search not working

Tags: php, joomla

On my website, I have the Smart Search module enabled. A search box does appear on my website, but when I try to search, I am getting a warning:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /public_html/component/finder/search was not found on this server.

I have all plugins enabled that have anything to do with Smart Search. As said, the module is enabled too. I think it is a silly 'wrong button' I pressed. Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** not only is this problem occurring in the search component, but it also occurs in all the other components (like ads and simple search). So it might be a general problem.

**Edit:** @Elin The problem is that when the component has to take action (e.g. when I click on a advertisement or do a search), the 'Not Found'-error occurs. So, I can't do a search, or click an ad, or anything else. The modules work fine, but if the component has to take action, it goes wrong.

Comment: Can you define "this problem"? is it that  same message? Are you using a SEF extension? Are menu links okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the mod-rewrite. I turned that function on, forgetting that mod_rewrite does not work on my virtual server (MAMP). Thanks for your comment @Elin!